# Error: cannot import name RemovedInDjango110Warning in django 1.9.5

Tags: django, celery

So this code has been running for like a week now, today it is throwing this error. And this is not happening at the URL level, which many places seem to say. 
I am using `celery`, `djcelery` and `Django 1.9.5`. In my celery task, in one part where I am trying to connect to my DB, it is throwing this error. The strange part is when I run the code line by line in shell, it works.

All this code runs inside a virtualenv being used by two projects which have exactly same requirements. to confirm, I just checked the django version in pip. It is 1.9.5

Please let me know if any extra info is required.

Comment: You need to show the code and the full error.

Comment: Please add traceback you are observing.

Comment: i ll try to add. problem is we are logging to sentry and that is giving timeout beautifully. i ll add traceback as soon as i get it